# How to rename column names with first row in polars?

Tags: python-polars

I have a polars dataframe and I want to set the first row as header. I thought about renaming the column name one by one with the value of the first row of the correspondent column. How can I do this in polars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[UPDATE]:** [@kirara0048's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75187317/how-to-rename-column-names-with-first-row-in-polars#comment132751390_75187496) of `.to_dicts()` is a much simpler approach.

```
>>> df.head(1).to_dicts().pop()
{'column_0': 'one', 'column_1': 'two', 'column_2': 'three'}
```

Which can be passed directly to `.rename()`

```
df.rename(df.head(1).to_dicts().pop())
```

---

Perhaps there is a more direct method but you could take the first row and `.transpose().to_series()`

```
>>> df = pl.DataFrame([["one", "four"], ["two", "five"], ["three", "six"]])
>>> df.head(1).transpose().to_series()
shape: (3,)
Series: 'column_0' [str]
[
    "one"
    "two"
    "three"
]
```

This can be used to create a dict of `old: new` and passed to `.rename()`

```
>>> df.rename(dict(zip(df.columns, df.head(1).transpose().to_series())))
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ one  | two  | three │
│ ---  | ---  | ---   │
│ str  | str  | str   │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ one  | two  | three │
├──────┼──────┼───────┤
│ four | five | six   │
└──────┴──────┴───────┘
```

`.slice(1)` can be used to "remove" the first row if desired:

```
>>> df.rename(dict(zip(df.columns, df.head(1).transpose().to_series()))).slice(1)
shape: (1, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ one  | two  | three │
│ ---  | ---  | ---   │
│ str  | str  | str   │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ four | five | six   │
└──────┴──────┴───────┘
```

You can also assign to `.columns` - I'm unsure if this is considered "bad style" or not.

```
>>> df.columns = df.head(1).transpose().to_series()
>>> df
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ one  | two  | three │
│ ---  | ---  | ---   │
│ str  | str  | str   │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ one  | two  | three │
├──────┼──────┼───────┤
│ four | five | six   │
└──────┴──────┴───────┘
```

Comment: It may be shorter to use `df.rename(df.to_dicts()[0])`.

Comment: @kirara0048 That is a much nicer approach! I kept the `.head(1)` as it seems wasteful to convert the whole dataframe when you only need the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is:

```
df.columns=df.iter_rows().__next__()
```

`iter_rows` makes a generator so it's not going to read any more of the df than the first row. If you don't like using the internal `__next__` then you could do

```
df.columns=df.head(1).rows()[0]
```

or

```
for row in df.iter_rows():
    df.columns=row
    break
```

or

```
rows=df.iter_rows()
df.columns=next(rows)
```